# How do you move all files and folders within a directory to the parent directory?

Tags: unix, directory, find, command, subdirectory

How do you move all files and folders within a directory from their sub directories to the parent directory? Including files within very deep folder directories.

What I would like to achieve is for when I am at `.` to convert this:

```
.
./aDir
./aDir/bFile
./aDir/cDir
./aDir/cDir/dDir
./aDir/cDir/dDir/eFile
```

To this:

```
.
./aDir
./bFile
./cDir
./dDir
./eFile
```

I assume you use the unix command `find` however I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I tried:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth * -print0 | xargs -0 mv -i -t ~/Desktop
```

Comment: The asterisk (*) is special to the shell.  Also the find I have won't take that as a value for maxdepth.  Since the default is 'as deep as possible, just remove `-maxdepth *`.  Also you asked to move files, but specified `-type d`?

Comment: Also you have no starting dir for find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking to un-nest your directory you'll need to mv them in depth first order, otherwise deeper directories could be mv'd inside the shallower ones.

Using very similar syntax to your attempt the following seems to do what is required.

```
find . -mindepth 2 -depth -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} ~/Desktop
```

Example:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d
./a/b/c2
./a/b/c
./a/b
./a
$ find . -mindepth 2 -depth -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} .
$ find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d
./a
./b
./c
./c2
```

Comment: I get the error `mv: ./a and ./a are identical` however I do get all the sub directories jumping into the parent directory. I however don't get any of the files within the directories umping into the parent directory. I've just used `mkdir` and `touch` to create a directory like your example but with files within the `a`,`b` & `c` directories

Comment: @joshuatvernon If you want all the files moved into the new location you can simply remove the `-type d` from the find command. 
I've edited the answer, it should be `-mindepth 2` to avoid that error

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
for i in $(find .); do cp -r $i .; done
```

When you are at `.` it converts this:

```
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
```

To this:

```
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
./c
./b
./b/c
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} .. \;
```

you might get this message

```
mv: cannot move `.' to `../.': Device or resource busy
```

But don't worry it is because '.' this directory is being attempted to move.

Comment: This is not the result the OP asked for.

Comment: This moved all the files and folders within the current directory one directory up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -depth -print0 | xargs -0 mv -i -t ~/Desktop
```

Comment: I get the error: `mv: illegal option -- t
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory`

Comment: Since he used `-t` in his example, I am assuming his `mv` supports that option...  If your `mv` doesn't use this xargs invocation: `xargs -0 -I{} mv {} ~/Desktop`